# How to get File Exception

Tags: vb.net

I've created an `.ini` file. I'm programming reading of the `.ini` file in `ini_class`. I want to know about just one thing in VB.NET.

I need a exception in read mode when file is not found. I searched in MSDN, I couldn't find anything yet.

Is this possible in VB.NET?

Comment: If you try to open the file for reading, the framework will throw the `FileNotFoundException` for you.  You don't need to do it yourself.  You can then re-throw the exception or do something with it.

Comment: But i want to see how to throw FileNotException in my program .     so, i try to read at wrong filepath. But not throw the FileNotException in my program. is this right the common phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an exception by using [`Throw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek.aspx).

> I need a exception about read mode, when file is not found.

You should use [`FileNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Throw New FileNotFoundException
```

Also take a look at [each constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.filenotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Here you can set a custom message:

```
Throw New FileNotFoundException("Could not open the stream: file not found.")
```